# Can s3 prefix be deleted on go-sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

In AWS cli, you can delete all items under prefix:

```
aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/prefix/ --recursive
```

I would like to delete all items under prefix just by giving prefix name.
Can this be done in go sdk? Closest answer I found was:

```
get keys from the `listobject`
deleteObjects(keys)
```

Comment: AWS SDK for go does expose a ‘Prefix’ parameter, you can define that in ListObjectsInput struct. Please check this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#ListObjectsInput

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The CLI provides added conveniences around the SDK; the SDK just provides what the API exposes. When you do `aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/prefix/ --recursive` in the CLI, the CLI's code does exactly what you described using the SDK: list all the objects with that prefix, then delete them. Don't expect all functionality in the CLI to be available in the SDK, just the functionality in the API.